# URL to Post Archive of Custom Query

Tags: wp-query, query, urls

1. I have a custom query for a CPT, from which I can obtain an array of postid's.
2. I want a url to the archive of the CPT, which has the query result (i.e. the posts of the postid's in the array are shown).
3. This url needs to go in a button as href value.

Comment: There aren’t standard URLs for an arbitrary list of IDs. What is the criteria you’re using to get these ids?

Comment: Actually its a pretty complex and referential series of queries (query from a post type -> list of linked taxonomy -> another query of the req. post type -> post_id array), a query inside query, i know it sounds weird.

Comment: But can't we make a function to do that? something like "abc.xyz/posttype/?post_id=534,323. I can do a bit of coding, but dont know where to start.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I want something like this https://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/filtering-views-query-by-post-id/

Comment: You'd need to edit the theme file for that CPT's archive so that it can accept your custom query string, parse it, and run a custom query.

Comment: Hmm... I tried and it worked. I used $_GET['post_ids'], parsed it using explode function, and used 'post__in' filter of wp_query. But the tricky part was to include it as a function, and using $query->set('post__in', $post_ids), because in archive page the query is already completed.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question seems weird, but here is how I was able to achieve it -

```
function filter_posts_by_id($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('CPT_NAME') && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $post_ids = $_GET['post_ids'];
    if(!empty($post_ids)) {
        $pids = explode(',',$_GET['post_ids']);
        $query->set('post__in', $pids); 
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts_by_id');
```

- PHP's predefined variable $_GET['parameter'] to get the query string
- PHP's explode() to convert comma-seperated query string to an array of post ids
- Wordpress WP_query function $query->set('parameter',$value) to set the wp query with the post_id filter
- Added the function to function.php of the theme and hooked with pre_get_posts so that the function runs before querying.
- Additionally set is_post_type_archive('post_type_name') to specifically target my CPT

Hope it helps others who got stuck there! This is the first time I am playing with Queries, so the code might not be the best.